# Forcing listener execution

Tags: java, listeners

I have a problem.

I have an object with a listener attached to it.

I'd like to be able to manually execute it, somehow trick it that the event that triggers it occurred. Maybe there's a way to access the specific listener and tell it to execute?

Object is Box.Filler and listener is ComponentListener (adapter, acctually). It's activated on ComponentResized event.

Comment: Sounds like an unusual design that for me has a code smell. Are you sure that this is the best way to obtain the behavior that you're after?

Comment: Probably not, but I have been messing with this thing for a while now, and with 500+ lines of code directly connected to that, this being the last puzzle peice, I really just want to be done with it...

I will maybe one day, when I start missing the coding, revisit the whole thing and rewrite it...

It a listener that changes thing in a way that it would invoke itself. I had to stop it from doing it while it executes, but it had to invoke itself afterwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you were using `ComponentListener` my guess is you could call it directly:

```
listener.componentResized(new ComponentEvent (this,id))
```

If you were using an adapter

```
adapter.componentResized(new ComponentEvent (this,id))
```

If your class implements ComponentListener

```
componentResized(new ComponentEvent (this,id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually fire an event. If you are using ComponentListener then you can use one of the methods listed in this interface, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html.

Comment: Depends on you object kind and the listened. Please provide more details